# Error extending entity with a observableArray in Breeze via constructor

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

If I try to extend an entity in Breeze via constructor with something like:

```
breeze.EntityManager('ServiceUrl').metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(
  'customer',
  function () {
    this.orders = ko.observableArray([]);
  }
);
```

I get a Knockout error when trying to set the new properties:

```
myCustomer.orders(newOrders);
```

The error is:

```
"Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters."
```

The same work if I add it in the post-construction initializer.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a required parameter -

```
breeze.EntityManager('ServiceUrl').metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(
  'customer', null,
  function () {
    this.orders = ko.observableArray([]);
  }
);
```

Your 'customer' parameter is required to identify the entity type.

The second parameter is a constructor (not for extending properties onto the entity)

The third is for initializing the entity

http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html#method_registerEntityTypeCtor

You also need to define the entity in your function -

```
breeze.EntityManager('ServiceUrl').metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(
  'customer',
  function (cust) {
    cust.orders = ko.observableArray([]);
  }
);
```